# Weird Chrome Developer Tools icon

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Normally, the chrome icon on the Developer Tools look like this:

[image]

But after I hibernated my computer and turned it back on again this morning, one of the windows had a weird icon like this (focus on the top-left corner):

[image]

It's not a loading icon as it's not moving. Is this a bug or does it have some meaning/story behind it?

Comment: You mean the warning icon indicating 3 warning messages?

Comment: @Ramhound Sorry I should have been clearer. But no, I mean the icon at the top-left corner.